# Bring one factor out of a sum using Lipschitz continuity

Tags: real-analysis, summation, factoring, lipschitz-functions

I'm currently doing my master's thesis and I have to work with Lipschitz continuous functions for the first time. I need to factor out a Lipschitz continuous function out of a sum, I have found a reasoning but it seems to my that I'm wrong.

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded Lipschitz continuous function and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be another bounded function.
Then we can say that for $T >0$:
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{1}{T}\sum_{m=1}^{T} f\left(\frac{m}{T}\right)g(m) &=  \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k} f\left(\frac{n+k}{T}\right)g(n+k)
\end{align}  $$
by substituting $m = n+k $   and now by using the Lipschitz continuity of $f$ we obtain,
$$ \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k} f\left(\frac{n+k}{T}\right)g(n+k) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k} f\left(\frac{k}{T}\right)g(n+k) + \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k} O(nT^{-1}) $$
we can finally factor out $f$ such that :
$$ \frac{1}{T}f\left(\frac{k}{T}\right)\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k}g(n+k) + \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k}O(nT^{-1}) $$
for all $k=1, \dots, T$.

It seems to me that my reasoning is wrong but I can't figure out why and where.

NB: This is my first post :)

Comment: You didn't specify what $n$ and $k$ are, other than their sum is the summation index. Shouldn't it be $$ \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k} f\left(\frac{n+k}{T}\right)g(n+k) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k} f\left(\frac{k}{T}\right)g(n+k) + \frac 1T\sum_{n=1-k}^{T-k} O(nT^{-1}) ?$$

Comment: @UmbertoP. I will edit my post since I meant $\forall k=1, \dots, T$ and $n$ is simply the summation index. I also meant your other remark about the remainder, I thought it was obvious as the remainder depends on $n$.